# Data management: how to add variables with conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I'd like to add 4 variables to my long format dataset and filter through it.
Basically I would start with 5 years (2016-2020). 2016 has more rows with respect to the other years, so I'd like to summarise 2016 to 2020 as new columns-variables copying their values to each row of 2016. In excel I would do this through SUMIFS. I've sort of managed in dplyr but I get 0s.

```
newdt <- dt %>% 
  group_by(time, country, age5, sex1, geo) %>% 
  summarise(T.age.2017 = sum(value[time==2017]),
         T.age.2018 = sum(value[time==2018]),
         T.age.2019 = sum(value[time==2019]),
         T.age.2020 = sum(value[time==2020])) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(time==2016)
```

Here's what I'd like to get, with filtering for time==2016 and keeping the other years only as summarized columns:

```
time    country geo   age5  sex1    value   T.age.2017  T.age.2018
2016    AT      AT11    0   1       6137    420814      427950
2016    AT      AT11    5   1       6582    411300      416616
2016    AT      AT11    10  1       6922    419810      418522
2016    AT      AT11    15  1       7461    444286      439986
2016    AT      AT11    0   2       5839    420814      427950
2016    AT      AT11    5   2       6354    411300      416616
2016    AT      AT11    10  2       6552    419810      418522
2016    AT      AT11    15  2       6769    444286      439986
2016    AT      AT12    0   1       39017   420814      427950
```

dput:

```
dt = structure(list(time = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), country = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AT", class = "factor"), 
geo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AT", 
"AT1", "AT11", "AT12", "AT13", "AT2", "AT21", "AT22", "AT3", 
"AT31", "AT32", "AT33", "AT34"), class = "factor"), age5 = c(0L, 
5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 
10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 
15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 
0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 
5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 
10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 
15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 
0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 
5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 
10L, 15L), sex1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), value = c(214538L, 210372L, 215218L, 
239274L, 200991L, 200273L, 203787L, 221272L, 94210L, 91724L, 
92439L, 100055L, 88171L, 87172L, 86792L, 93008L, 6137L, 6582L, 
6922L, 7461L, 5839L, 6354L, 6552L, 6769L, 39017L, 40381L, 
43136L, 47241L, 36855L, 38487L, 40292L, 42981L, 49056L, 44761L, 
42381L, 45353L, 45477L, 42331L, 39948L, 43258L, 40212L, 40464L, 
41996L, 47804L, 37323L, 38646L, 39861L, 44218L, 12266L, 12928L, 
13451L, 15108L, 11554L, 12204L, 12827L, 13938L, 27946L, 27536L, 
28545L, 32696L, 25769L, 26442L, 27034L, 30280L, 80116L, 78184L, 
80783L, 91415L, 75497L, 74455L, 77134L, 84046L, 37488L, 36674L, 
37456L, 42495L, 35219L, 34859L, 35959L, 38955L, 13774L, 13185L, 
14012L, 16206L, 12907L, 12629L, 13265L, 14534L, 18414L, 17944L, 
18544L, 20879L, 17482L, 17045L, 17609L, 19752L, 10440L, 10381L, 
10771L, 11835L, 9889L, 9922L, 10301L, 10805L, 420814L, 411300L, 
419810L, 444286L, 427950L, 416616L, 418522L, 439986L, 435796L, 
420548L, 420646L, 436501L, 444137L, 425721L, 420044L, 437446L
)), .Names = c("time", "country", "geo", "age5", "sex1", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -120L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(time, country, age5, sex1, geo) %>% 
  summarise(T.age = sum(value)) %>% 
  filter(time==2016) %>% 
  left_join(.,dt %>% 
              group_by(time, country, age5, geo) %>% 
              summarise(T.age = sum(value)) %>% 
              mutate(time2 = 2016) %>% 
              filter(time != 2016) %>% 
              spread(time, T.age),
            by = c('time' = 'time2', 'country', 'age5')) %>% 
  select(-geo.y) %>% 
  arrange(time, country, geo.x, sex1, age5)
```

The result of that:

```
# A tibble: 104 x 10
# Groups:   time, country, age5, sex1 [8]
    time country  age5  sex1  geo.x  T.age `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
   <dbl>  <fctr> <int> <int> <fctr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1  2016      AT     0     1     AT 214538 420814 427950 435796 444137
 2  2016      AT     5     1     AT 210372 411300 416616 420548 425721
 3  2016      AT    10     1     AT 215218 419810 418522 420646 420044
 4  2016      AT    15     1     AT 239274 444286 439986 436501 437446
 5  2016      AT     0     2     AT 200991 420814 427950 435796 444137
 6  2016      AT     5     2     AT 200273 411300 416616 420548 425721
 7  2016      AT    10     2     AT 203787 419810 418522 420646 420044
 8  2016      AT    15     2     AT 221272 444286 439986 436501 437446
 9  2016      AT     0     1    AT1  94210 420814 427950 435796 444137
10  2016      AT     5     1    AT1  91724 411300 416616 420548 425721
# ... with 94 more rows
```